# Uploadify mvc2 HTTP POST not alowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, uploadify

Hi i did everything like in this tutorial [click](http://techblog.edwardting.com/2011/05/20/multiple-file-upload-in-mvc-using-uploadify/)

but when i try to upload the files, each time i got POST not allowed error, i checked in fiddler and GET works for example:

```
GET /Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1348057301853 HTTP/1.1
```

but Post not

```
POST /Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf HTTP/1.1
```

header of my controller method looks like :

```
[HttpPost]
public string UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase FileData, FormCollection forms)
{
```

and jquery implementation like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Multiple files - single input
var auth = "<% = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]==null ? string.Empty : Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value %>";
var ASPSESSID = "dfgdf";
var entryID = "<%= ViewData["EntryID"] %>";

$("#file_upload").uploadify({
'uploader': '<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf") %>',
'script': '<%= Url.Action("uploadFiles","Home") %>',
'scriptData': { ASPSESSID: ASPSESSID, AUTHID: auth, entryID: entryID },
'fileDataName': 'FileData',
'buttonText': 'Select files',
'multi': true,
'width': 250,
'sizeLimit': 200000000,
'simUploadLimit': 1,
'cancelImg': '<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify-cancel.png") %>',
'folder': '/Content',
'auto': false,
'removeCompleted' : false,
'onAllComplete' : function(event,data) {
alert(data.filesUploaded + ' files uploaded successfully!');

},
'onSelectOnce' : function(event,data) {
$("#uploadLink").show();
}

});

});
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would share some of your code. By looking at the tutorial you should start by adding [HttpPost] attribute over uploadFiles method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the tutorial is refering to some older version of *Uploadify*, now the options are a little bit different, you can find up-to-date list [here](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/).

I have updated your code (I have commented options which doesn't seem to exist anymore):

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify({
    'swf': '<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf") %>',
    'uploader': '<%= Url.Action("uploadFiles","Home") %>',
    'formData': { ASPSESSID: ASPSESSID, AUTHID: auth, entryID: entryID },
    'fileObjName': 'FileData',
    'buttonText': 'Select files',
    'multi': true,
    'width': 250,
    'fileSizeLimit': 200000000,
    //'simUploadLimit': 1,
    //'cancelImg': '<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify-cancel.png") %>',
    //'folder': '/Content',
    'auto': false,
    'removeCompleted': false,
    'onQueueComplete': function(event,data) {
        alert(data.filesUploaded + ' files uploaded successfully!');
    },
    'onSelect' : function(event,data) {
        $("#uploadLink").show();
    }
});
```